# Jquery url replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I modify this:

```
/services/type/single_dwelling/
```

to this:

`/ajax/services/single_dwelling/development`

Currently I have:

```
linkUrl = $(this).attr("href").replace(/(\/(services)\/)/,"$1ajax/");
```

Which outputs:

```
/services/ajax/type/single_dwelling/
```

I'm a little confused.

Comment: Nicely formatted question. Short, sweet, informative and to the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking carefully I see you want to prepend `'/ajax'`, remove `'/type'` from the original url, and append `'development'`:

```
var linkUrl = '/ajax' + $(this).attr("href").replace('type/','') + 'development';
```

That will output `"/ajax/services/single_dwelling/development"` using your test string.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
linkUrl = "/ajax" + $(this).attr("href").replace("/type", "") + "development";
```